# Xcode Swift compiler warning will never be executed

Tags: xcode, swift

I have code in this vein:

```
enum enumThingType {
    case apples
    case oranges
    case starfruit
}

func myFunc( enumThing: enumThingType ) -> String {
    switch enumThing {
    case .apples:
        return "Hey, apples"
    case .oranges:
        return "Hey, oranges"        
    default:
        return ""
    }
}
```

I'm very slowly filling in the code for all of the cases, and I have need of the code to be functional while I code for *starfruit* and its ilk.

All is good, but the compiler issues the warning **will never be executed** for `return ""`. It happily generates an executable, but I am compulsive and would like warnings and errors to go away.

If I delete the line `return ""`, then I get the very real and compiler arresting **Missing return in a function expected to return 'String'**.

Likewise, if I just delete `default:`..., I get the equally arresting error **Switch must be exhaustive, consider adding a default clause**, which is fully understandable, but I am creative in my efforts to thwart warnings and errors.

So given this construct, can I eliminate warnings and errors while still coding for existing cases for `myFunc`?

**EDIT**

As @appzYourLife pointed out, I omitted precompiler directives in my sample code that were creating the error. This code, with the precompiler directives, throws a warning:

```
enum enumThingType {
    case apples
    case oranges
    case starfruit
}

func myFunc( enumThing: enumThingType ) -> String {
    switch enumThing {
    case .apples:
        return "Hey, apples"
    case .oranges:
        return "Hey, oranges"        
    default:
    #if DEBUG
        print( "Ouch!" )
    #else
        fatalError()
    #endif
        return ""
    }
}
```

Because if the product is not created with DEBUG specified, then return can never happen--the `FatalError()` prevents that.

This code, however, *does not* throw a warning for all precompiler specified cases:

```
func myFunc( enumThing: enumThingType ) -> String {
    switch enumThing {
    case .apples:
        return "Hey, apples"
    case .oranges:
        return "Hey, oranges"        
    default:
    #if DEBUG
        print( "Ouch!" )
        return ""
    #else
        fatalError()
    #endif
    }
}
```

I just wanted to summarize the actual code fix for anyone who might gander across this, as the lack of a properly specified DEBUG flag fixed it for a DEBUG condition, but not for a non DEBUG condition. Thanks again for everyone who helped on this!

Comment: What happens if you replace the default with a case for starfruiit?

Comment: @LouFranco, right now there are about 20 starfruits. I could code a "not yet available" for each one, but I'm curious if that's not an absolute necessity.

Comment: "All is good, but the compiler issues the warning will never be executed for `return ""`" Okay, but then why not say `default:break`? I can't test this because with the code you've shown, I get no warning!

Comment: @matt, Then I get the error, "Missing return in a function expected to return 'String'". I spent a lot of time waiting to post this, because I couldn't come up with a self contained set of code to generate the error, hence the "in the vein" construct for the question, and also the very expected cruel downvote for something that Xcode is detecting that can't be simply rendered in a code snippet. It's clear that Xcode is smart enough to wander through all possibilities and decide that the default would never be executed, but I'm curious if there's a different algorithmic construct. Ideas?

Comment: I'm happy to help as soon as you show your real code! I repeat: the code you've provided doesn't generate the warning you claim. So this is an unreproducible result. Show me actual code that generates the warning and I'll tell you how I'd solve it.

Comment: @matt, I am so happy to dump the whole project--it's a bitbucket git, but do you really want that? I avoid that according the laws of stackoverflow nature and decorum. What's your desire?

Comment: Gosh, I've no objection. If the bitbucket is public, tell me what it is and I'll download it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104072/discussion-between-dribbler-and-matt).

Comment: Downloaded your code but it doesn't reproduce the problem either: it builds with no issues.

Comment: @matt, really, with no warnings? As I wrote, it compiles an executable, but I am compulsive and would prefer no warnings.

Comment: Come back into the chat room, I've posted a screen shot that shows I build with no warnings, no errors, no nothing.

Comment: @matt posted the screen shot in chat that shows my warning...

Comment: I'm not getting that warning. What version of Xcode are you using?

Comment: Thanks so much for the kind effort, matt! @appzYourLife figured it out--I had DEBUG miss-set in this project. Egads. Many, many, many thanks.j

Comment: So, you admit you totally lied to us! :)))

Comment: Yes, @matt, I own my mistakes ;) Thanks so much for digging in!

Comment: Thanks for letting me see the program! I didn't try running it but it's just the sort of thing I like. Best of luck with it.

Comment: It's my way of doing flashcards for learning Spanish, @matt. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I follow the chat you had with *@matt*, so it looks like the code you posted in your question was **NOT** the real code ;)

The real code is more something like this

```
func myFunc( enumThing: enumThingType ) -> String {
    switch enumThing {
    case .apples:
        return "Hey, apples"
    case .oranges:
        return "Hey, oranges"
    default:
        #if DEBUG
        print("...")
        #else
        fatalError()
        #endif
        return ""
    }
}
```

Now I am getting your warning and it is totally correct.

In fact since `DEBUG` is **NOT** defined, the `#else` block will be executed.

So the `fatalError()` will be executed.

And since you are putting a `return ""` immediately after a `fatalError()`... well the `return` of course will never be executed.

The compiler is right.

### Update: defining the DEBUG complier flag

1. Open the project root
2. Select your target
3. Look for the `Swift Compiler - Custom Flags` section
4. Add to debug or release this entry: `-D DEBUG`

[image]

Comment: Thanks for doing the deep dive, @appzYourLife. I defined DEBUG in the compiler. If you delete all of the precompiler code, it still issues the warning.

Comment: I defined the `DEBUG` too in my test project and it **removed** the warning... Are you sure you defined the DEBUG compiler flag correctly?

Comment: Unbelievable, @appzYourLife, I had "-DDEBUG" rather than "-D DEBUG" for this project. Talk about inattentional blindness ;) Thank you so much for putting so much effort into this. Error gone.